# LIbSVM of Weka in C# with IKVM

Tags: c#, reflection, weka, libsvm, ikvm

I am using the [weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) machine learning library in C# with [IKVM](https://www.ikvm.net/). So far it worked very well, however, I am having problem using the [libSVM](https://weka.wikispaces.com/LibSVM) package.

The problem appears when I want to instantiate the libsvm classifier in C# (the class is not found), as it is advised:

```
AbstractClassifier classifier = (AbstractClassifier)java.lang.Class.forName("weka.classifiers.functions.LibSVM").newInstance();
```

What I tried:

- Add the the libsvm.dll and weka.dll to the project (converted from libsvm.jar and weka.jar)
- Merge libsvm.jar and weka.jar into one dll and add it to the project (using ikvm or ilmerge)

Note that the package is installed since it appears in the result of

```
WekaPackageManager.getInstalledPackages();
```

Has anyone every succeeded using Weka with LibSVM in C# using IKVM?

Thanks,
Botond

Answer (score 0):

I hava the same problem ,but I found a solution from the website:[here](http://weka.8497.n7.nabble.com/IKVM-with-LibSVM-td38017.html).

I use weka.jar(version 3.6) and get the libsvm package from weka 3.8 
{HOME}/wekafiles/packages/LibSVM

Step 1. You will need: weka.jar, Libsvm.jar(LibSVM/LibSVM.jar), libsvm.jar (LibSVM/lib/libsvm.jar).

Step 2. Rename Libsvm.jar to Libsvm1.jar.

Step 3. Run in IKVM: open command line and go to the ikvm's bin folder

```
    ikvmc.exe -sharedclassloader -target:library weka.jar libsvm.jar LibSVM1.jar
```

Step 4. Reference the generated weka.dll in your C# project.

Step 5.Sample code in c#

```
LibSVM svm = new LibSVM();
svm.setOptions(weka.core.Utils.splitOptions("-S 3 -K 2 -D 3 -G 0.0 -R 0.0 -N 0.5 -M 40.0 -C 1.0 -E 0.001 -P 0.1 -seed 1"));
svm.buildClassifier(dataset);
```